# Merging gridview cells with templatefields

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to format a gridview during the onrowdatabound event were I need to merge column cells with like values. It works find except for one of my columns which is a templatefield with a linkbutton inside. The code reads blanks when it iterates through the templatefield column and merges the entire column into a single cell.

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdSummary" runat="server" onrowdatabound="grdSummary_RowDataBound" >
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Period" >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Linkbutton ID="lnkPeriod" runat="server" CssClass="LinkbuttonCellStyle"
                                            Text='<%# Eval("Period") %>' OnClick="lnkQuarterSummary_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Period") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Timeline" DataField="Timeline" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Americas" DataField="Americas" DataFormatString="{0:#,0}" ItemStyle-CssClass="SummaryGridCellStyle" />                                    
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Codebehind:

```
Protected Sub grdSummary_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    For rowIndex As Integer = grdSummary.Rows.Count - 2 To 0 Step -1

        Dim grdRow As GridViewRow = grdSummary.Rows(rowIndex)
        Dim grdPreviousRow As GridViewRow = grdSummary.Rows(rowIndex + 1)

        For cellCount As Integer = 0 To 0

            If grdRow.Cells(cellCount).Text = grdPreviousRow.Cells(cellCount).Text Then

                If grdPreviousRow.Cells(cellCount).RowSpan < 2 Then

                    grdRow.Cells(cellCount).RowSpan = 2

                Else

                    grdRow.Cells(cellCount).RowSpan = grdPreviousRow.Cells(cellCount).RowSpan + 1

                End If

                grdPreviousRow.Cells(cellCount).Visible = False

            End If

        Next cellCount

    Next rowIndex

End Sub
```

I'm able to read the templatefield value using this:

```
Dim test As String = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Period")
```

but I can only read the current row, not the previous one as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you loop the rows in `RowDataBound` which is triggered for _every_ row in the grid anyway? Maybe you want to use the [`DataBound` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound(v=vs.110).aspx) instead which is only raised once.

Comment: That's a good point but the original problem still remains. I can only read the value for the current row of the templatefield column.

Comment: You have to use the `DataItem` to access the datasource of a given `GridViewRow`. So you can cast `grdRow.DataItem`to the real type(f.e. `DataRowView`).

Comment: I'm still struggling with this, can you give me a sample snippet to read the specific gridview row?